# separate traffic between 2 different connections

Tags: centos, gateway

We have:

- 1 LAN with dhcp and 2 gateways: 1 only for our voip provider, 1 for internet
- a lot of PCs
- 1 server centos used for VOIP purpose

suppose lan is 192.168.0.0/24, we have GW1 (internet) at 192.168.0.1 and GW2 (voip) at 192.168.0.2.

How can I separate traffic sending voip to 192.168.0.2 and all the other things (especially SSH) to 192.168.0.1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Policy Based Routing that is controlled by iproute2: refer for example to http://lartc.org/howto/

If XXXXXX is the source of your VoIP traffic and eth0 is the network interface, something like the following could work

```
# echo 1 VOIP >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# ip route add default via 192.168.0.2 dev eth0 table VOIP
# ip rule add from XXXXXX table VOIP
```

Of course this has to be customized for your specific case, especially for the

```
ip rule
```

part

Comment: I'm not sure it will work: the fact is that I don't know what is the final ip that provider use during a call. I mean, I know the ip for SIP registration, but generally it routes me to an other server that with SIP establish the RTP traffic with my asterisk box...

The voip provider IP work as a SIP proxy only for session start and registration, but RTP traffic (voice) and SIP packets generally comes from a random server in a pool...

Can I route traffic by type?

EG. Sip & RTP -> 192.168.0.2; ALL -> 192.168.0.1

Probably it could be the best idea...